# How to write test cases to cover all the nested 'then' callbacks in a promise chain

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm having difficulty covering the entire promise chain in my unit test coverage. I did find articles that gave me the nearest solution but the challenge is at the last 'then' I need to call three function that does not return a promise.

**Below is the example/Sample I tried**

```
async = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('value');
});

async1 = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('value1');
});

async2 = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve('Final Value');
});


it('test my scenario', (done) => {
  someChainPromisesMethod()
    .then(data => {
      expect(async1).toBeCalledWith('value');
      expect(async2).toBeCalledWith('value1');
      expect(data).toEqual('Final Value');
      done(); 
  });
});
```

**Below is the function which returns another function with nested 'then' functions. I need help with the test cases to cover them all.**

```
function consolidatedReport(param1, param2){

   const somedata = param1.data;
   const someOtherData = param2.data;

  if(true){ 
     doThisthing(); 
   }

  return promiseChainBegin(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionOne(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionTwo(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionThree(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => response && functionFour(somedata, someOtherData)
    .then(response => {
       if(response) {
           notApromiseFuncOne(somedata)(someOtherData);
           notApromiseFuncTwo(somedata)(someOtherData);
           notApromiseFuncThree(somedata)(someOtherData);
        } else{
           notApromiseFailCase(someOtherData);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm having difficulty covering the nested then functions.

Comment: Can you update your question with code that more accurately shows what you are trying to test?  In the code above nothing is being returned from the final `then` callback so `data` could never be `Final Value` in your test...I'm guessing `consolidatedReport` was simplified for the question but its functionality got changed in the process.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors In a eCommerce website, when a user clicks checkout. consolidatedReport gets called, promiseChainBegin returns items in cart. functionOne is fetching his preferred address. FunctionTwo is fetching his preferred payment. functionThree is checking for his preferred delivery time etc. Istanbul coverage report shows functionOne, functionTwo, three, four etc are all not covered. I just want to ensure they are called and covered in the coverage report.

Comment: Sounds like you are mocking those functions in your test so they aren't actually called.  If you want code coverage on them you'll have to let them actually get called and instead mock what they are doing (sounds like they make API calls so you'll need to mock those)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd mock each of `functionOne`, etc resolved values:

```
import functionOne from '../path/to/functionOne';
import functionTwo from '../path/to/functionTwo';
import functionThree from '../path/to/functionThree';

jest.mock('../path/to/functionOne');
jest.mock('../path/to/functionTwo');
jest.mock('../path/to/functionThree');

it('test my scenario', () => {
  functionOne.mockResolvedValue('value 1');
  functionTwo.mockResolvedValue('value 2');
  functionTwo.mockResolvedValue('value 3');

  return someChainPromisesMethod()
    .then(data => {
      expect(functionOne).toBeCalledWith('value returned by promise');
      expect(functionTwo).toBeCalledWith('value 1');
      expect(functionThree).toBeCalledWith('value 2');

      expect(data).toEqual('Final Value');
  });
});
```

This is not exactly your code, but the idea goes like that. You mock the resolved value for each of your functions.